# How to answer "show that" and "verify" type of questions?

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

I have been doing some exercises and found that there are contradicting response in regard to answering the "show that" type of question.

> First exercise,
>
> Consider the vectors $a = 4\sqrt{2}\hat i+\hat j+2\hat k$ and $b =
> > \hat i-\sqrt{2} \hat j-c\hat k$, show that $a$ is perpendicular to $b$
> when $c = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Based on the marking guide, you are suppose to substitute $\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$ into $c$ and take the dot product.

> A second different exercise,
>
> Show that the roots of $z^2 + 4z + 16= 0$ are $z=-2-2\sqrt{3}i$ and
> $z=-2+2\sqrt{3}i$

Now based on this marking scheme, I must use quadratic or completing the square to find the given answer.

SO now what?!?!? Does a "show that" question requires me to find the given answer or using a method of substitution to confirm that the given answer is correct?

In addition, how does a "show that" question differ from a "verify" type of problem?

update:

> [image]

Comment: You will see the words/phrases "show that", "verify", "demonstrate", "prove" used in problem statements, and they are mostly synonymous to each other. None of these words have any implication on *how* you will do it - the *means* of showing/proving/demonstrating/verifying are *entirely up to you*. For the latter, you should've learned some techniques in your lessons: you should use an appropriate technique and you must not make reasoning mistakes. (Often, calculation mistakes would be, at least partially, forgiven.)

Comment: (Cont'd): For instance: in the second example, I would consider it an equally valid solution if either: (a) You completed the square/used the formula, solved the equation and showed that the two solutions are $-2\pm 2\sqrt{3}i$, or (b) You substituted $z=-2\pm 2\sqrt{3}i$ (both of them!) into $z^2+4z+16$ and found that it is equal to $0$ *and* mentioned, because it is a non-zero quadratic, it can only have up to two zeros, so those zeros are the only ones.

Comment: On the second exercise, using the quadratic equation and completing the square are methods for *finding* the roots, if you do not yet know what they are. But in this problem the roots are handed to you on a silver platter, and you don't need to use the quadratic equation nor completing the square to *show* that they are the roots. So I would say that question 2 is a trick question, tempting you to waste your mathematical energies on a computationally difficult task (quadratic equation; completing the square) when there is a very easy method at hand (substitution).

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks for commenting, look at the update the official marking scheme says otherwise?

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for answering, mind looking at the snippet I took? Thanks

Comment: I think this is a subtle grammar issue. If it was "Show that ... are roots" you can use substitution. However, it is "Show that the roots are ...", so besides showing that those are indeed the roots, you must also show that there are *no more roots* to the equation, via quadratic formula or the like. Although one can accomplish that by invoking the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, that is clearly not the intention of the question markers.

Comment: @player3236 I would then say that this question is a dangerously close to a trick question. The examiners had so many chances to word it less ambiguously (e.g. "Solve the equation $z^2+4z+6=0$ and thus show that the roots are...) - or to essentially test the same knowledge, simply: "Solve the equation...". Insist on showing that some numbers are roots, but then insisting that the equation still needs to be solved, with (I guess) at that stage common knowledge that a quadratic has at most two roots is disingenuous. My day has just been ruined.

Comment: IMO, the author "equates" "show that" to prove more than to verify. Thus, the approach to 1st Exercise is to compute dot product and apply condition of perpendicularity: solving the equation, you will produce the expected value of $c$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It is apparently not the same author. In *that* question they were *supposed* to substitute $c$, and probably the way you said it could be done would be considered incorrect. Appalling.

Comment: One more thing: @Negrawh - have you considered posting this also to https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/  ? - That site is more about *teaching* mathematics rather than mathematics itself. I wonder what the feedback (from actual math teachers, primarily) would be.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Right, I apologise and many thanks again for helping :)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yeah you are right, I got those 2 questions from different exercise books.

Comment: That is a relief to know. I was afraid that the questions may have been asked on an exam of some sort, and that you may have been downmarked due to providing an answer "not as in the book".